# $M=X\cup Y$. If $S\subset M$ is open in $S\cup X$ and open in $S\cup Y$ then $S$ is open in $M$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $M=X\cup Y$ be a metric space. If $S\subset M$ is open in $S\cup X$ and open in $S\cup Y$ then $S$ is open in $M$.

I can't do anything with this exercise. I think that is the hardest problem in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $S$ is open in $S\cup X$, there must be an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $U\cap(S\cup X)=S$. Similarly, since $S$ is open in $S\cup Y$, there must be an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $V\cap(S\cup Y)=S$. Clearly $S\subseteq U$, so $U\cap S = S$, and $$S=U\cap(S\cup X)=(U\cap S)\cup(U\cap X)=S\cup(U\cap X)\;,$$ and therefore $U\cap X\subseteq S$. Similarly, $S\subseteq V$, so $$S=V\cap(S\cup Y)=(V\cap S)\cup(V\cap Y)=S\cup(V\cap Y)\;,$$ and therefore $V\cap Y\subseteq S$.

Next, note that $S\subseteq U\cap V$; $U\cap V$ is open in $M$, so we’re done if we can show that $S=U\cap V$. We know that $U\cap X\subseteq S$, so certainly $U\cap V\cap X\subseteq S$. Similarly, from $V\cap Y\subseteq S$ we can infer that $U\cap V\cap Y\subseteq S$. But then

$$\begin{align*}
U\cap V&=(U\cap V)\cap M\\
&=(U\cap V)\cap(X\cup Y)\\
&=(U\cap V\cap X)\cup(U\cap V\cap Y)\\
&\subseteq S\;,
\end{align*}$$

so indeed $U\cap V=S$.

As you can see, the result is valid for topological spaces in general, not just for metric spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't note the fact that $S\subset U$ and $S\subset V$.

Comment: Is the same if $S$ is closed in both sets. Then $S$ is closed in $M$. Only fact that do you use is that intersection of two closed sets is closed and intersection of two open sets is open.

Comment: @Gastón: Yes, that’s right.